# Monitoring memory usage in time

Tags: windows-10, memory

I crash in a game and as it is a brutal crash without warning I think it is probably caused by the fact the memory is saturated.

I would like to check it, and thus I need to have access to both GPU memory and RAM memory history.

I know that in windows I can see it in the task manager. The problem is that it only shows the last 60s of usage.

How can I have a nice history of memory usage ? I would like to be able to extract the info so that I can see if indeed at some point my memory has been saturated at least in the last 3mn or so.

Comment: Look at Windows Admin Tools, Resource Monitor. It can show you basic measurements over time including CPU. I do not see a GPU addition at this point

Comment: @John I found this earlier but I don't see where I can increase to something like 5mn the records, and to save them as well ?

Comment: You are making assumptions without showing us any justification for them. You need to analyse what actually happens at the crash rather than leap to it being an out of memory error. OOM errors would announce themselves to you. This is currently an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: If you wish to save Resource Monitor to a file. you would need to use Performance Monitor and create a data collection set.